# how to enable libvorbis codec in ffmpeg windows? and how convert from .mov to .webm

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg-20140717-git-fa6716c-win64-shared latest one and they have mentioned 
--enable-libvirbose .

but once I run the command to convert .mov to .webm then its saying unknown encoder libvorbis

I am not able to enable libvorbis in ffmpeg windows.

what command to enable any codec.

and I am trying to convert .mov to .webm format with this command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -codec:v libvpx -quality good -cpu-used 0 -b:v 225k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 300k -bufsize 1000k -threads 2 -vf scale=-1:560 -codec:a libvorbis -b:a 128k -pass 2 -f webm output.webm
```

but its having an error of:

```
Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format

Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1
```

and even in command I added some -pix_fmt value like

1] -pix_fmt yuv420p
2] -pix_fmt yuv422p
 and many more but still giving same error as I have mentioned...

and my .mov file is very high HD file.

please guide me what to write

Thank You.

Comment: guys need help..!! please help me out

Answer (score 0):

type **ffmpeg.exe -h** and look for the **--enable-libvorbis** like below. if you cannot see the **--enable-libvorbis**, you should download **libvorbis enabled ffmpeg** from [Zeranoe FFmpeg - Builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

> e:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -h
>   ffmpeg version N-62699-gc7b0890 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
>     built on Apr 25 2014 03:07:38 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
>     configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads 
>     --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r 
>     --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray 
>     --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc 
>     --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb 
>     --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus 
>     --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex 
>     --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc 
>     **--enable-libvorbis** --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 
>     --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib

Generic converter parameters should work, if it works, step by step try other parameters. (-b:a 256k fails with wrong parameters 192k OK.)

**ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx -b:v 2000k -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k -f webm output.webm**

**ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx -b:v 2000k -vf scale=-1:560 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k -f webm output.webm**

**ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx -b:v 2000k -bufsize 4000k -muxrate 4000k -vf scale=-1:560 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k -f webm output.webm**

Two Pass

Pass 1

**ffmpeg -i input.mov -pass 1 -passlogfile "c:\pass1.log" -c:v libvpx -b:v 2000k -f webm -sn -an output.webm**

Pass 2

**ffmpeg -i input.mov -pass 2 -passlogfile "c:\pass1.log" -c:v libvpx -b:v 2000k -f webm -sn -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k output.webm**

Two Pass with single command line

**ffmpeg -i input.mov -pass 1 -passlogfile "c:\pass1.log" -c:v libvpx -b:v 2000k -f webm -sn -an output.webm && ffmpeg -i input.mov -pass 2 -passlogfile "c:\pass1.log" -c:v libvpx -b:v 2000k -f webm -sn -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k output.webm**

also increasing the -bufsize (-bufsize 4000k) may help.

Comment: Thank you khan for your valuable answer..

I did it as per you said, but it has already mentioned --enable-libvorbis

I have a latest version also

Comment: actually my concern is if we are getting any error like

Unknown encoder found : 'libfaac'

then how to add that encoder explicitly

like I run one command there I am getting error regarding libfaac 

so how to add that libfaac 

P.S I am using latest version of ffmpeg